# perpareForSegue - Passing image name - Blank at First

Tags: ios5

I have a thumbnail view controller with two thumbnails. Each have an IBAction setting the image name. The next view should display the full image.

The first time I select a button, the new view opens but is completely blank. I go back to the previous screen (navigation controller) and select the button again and the full image screen shows with the correct full image.

Back out, select the second button and the full image of the first button is displayed.

It appears that the full image is off by one iteration.

Below are some code snippets.

thumbnailViewController.M

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    fullImageViewController *targetVC = (fullImageViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
targetVC.fullImageName = _imageName;
}

- (IBAction)running1 {
_imageName = @"img_running1.png";
}

- (IBAction)running2 {
_imageName = @"img_running2.png";
}
```

fullImageViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
_fullImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: _fullImageName];
}
```

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have both the IBAction and the Segue hooked up to your buttons? If so this is your issue. The segue occurs before the IBAction. The solution is instead of having the button hooked up to the segue have the IBAction perform it.

```
- (IBAction)running1 {
    _imageName = @"img_running1.png";
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegue" sender:self];
}
```

This will correct the order by giving you control. otherwise I believe its segue then action.

Comment: thanks Ryan. I appreciate your help. I was getting an error but I found that if I added send:self it worked. [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegue" sender:self];

Comment: Yes sorry should have mentioned I didn't write it in Xcode. Happy Coding :)